# Crontab won't run for user

Tags: unix, cron

I'm trying to run crontab as a user, but any of the scripts won't execute. How I can fix this? Consider that:

- I tried with BOTH `crontab -e` and `sudo crontab -u username -e;`
- Scripts are correctly written, since they are executed if I run them
  with root crontab;
- In cron.allow there are both root and user.

Answer (score 3):

**Crontab Permissions**:

There are two files that control the permissions for crontab: `/etc/cron.allow` and `/etc/cron.deny`.

If there is a `cron.allow` file, then the user or users that need to use cron will need to be listed in the file. You can use `cron.deny` to explicitly disallow certain users from using cron.

**If neither files exist, then only the super user is allowed to run cron.** Well, that depends on the system specific configuration to be exact. Most configuration do not allow any users to run jobs, while some systems allow all users to run jobs by default.

So, the first step is to create a file named `cron.allow` in the `/etc/` folder. Add the user name to this file in order to allow the user to run jobs.

Once the proper permissions has been set, the user should be able to modify and run jobs using the **crontab** command.